# Cannot access SQL Server database using jtds

Tags: java, sql-server, jtds

I am trying to access a SQL Server database using Java and jtds.  This is my (very) simple code:

```
String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://dev.company.com:1433/master;domain=COMP;USENTLMV2=true;SSL=request";
String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
String userName = "COMP\\username";
String password = "s3cr3t";
Connection conn = null;

try {
    Class.forName(driver);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    conn.close();
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

After a few minutes of no activity, I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection reset
    ....
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    ....
```

I can ping dev.company.com, and I can access the database using a GUI (SQLPro for my Mac) so it's a valid connection, but I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Is TCP/IP enabled in the SQL Server instance?

Comment: Unrelated, but: the jTDS driver is pretty dead and hasn't be updated in a long time. Nowadays the Microsoft JDBC driver is the better choice: https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc

Comment: I don't know if TCP/IP is enabled.  I was told specifically to use jtds....

Comment: this is a bug https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-39866

Comment: Interesting...Thanks TCF_L.  If I'm reading this right, it says there is a patch available.  How would I implement the patch?

Answer (score 0):

Please move away from JTDS. Their last release was ion 2012. As per one of the developers of JTDS (Nida ), the project has ceased all active development activities.

Please use SQLJdbc42 driver from Microsoft which is quite stable.

I am suffering from a JTDS issue with SQL Server on SSL and got the confirmation that this project is DEAD.