# Cannot access SQL Server database using JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database using JDBC.  I was given a connection string using JTDS, but that isn't working ([I asked a question about this yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43792672/cannot-access-sql-server-database-using-jtds)) so I'm trying to convert it to JDBC.  I am able to connect using the credentials on SQLPro, so I know the credentials are good, but it will not work in code.  This was the JTDS connection string I was given:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://dev.company.com:1433/master;domain=COMP;USENTLMV2=true;SSL=request
```

This is my code, having tried to convert it to JDBC

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://dev.company.com:1433;databaseName=master;domain=COMP;USENTLMV2=true;SSL=request";
String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
String userName = "COMP\\user";
String password = "s3cr3t";
Connection conn = null;

try {
    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    conn.close();
}
```

I downloaded the [driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774) and used Maven install:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/Users/kroe761/Documents/workspace/project/sqljdbc42.jar -DgroupId=microsoft.jdbs -DartifactId=jdbs.server -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

And then in my pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>microsoft.jdbs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdbs.server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But, I keep getting this a login error

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'COMP\user'.
```

I also tried doing it this way.  I got the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` from the x64 folder when I downloaded the driver:

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://dev.company.com:1433;databaseName=master;integratedSecurity=true";
String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
String userName = "COMP\\user";
String password = "s3cr3t";
Connection conn = null;

try {
    java.lang.System.load("/Users/kroe761/Documents/workspace/project/sqljdbc_auth.dll");
    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    conn.close();  // line 26
}
```

But then I get this error - very unhelpful.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at kroe761.playground.App.main(App.java:26)
```

Comment: The path in your code suggests you are using Linux or macOS, so you can't use `sqljdbc_auth.dll`. You will either need to use SQL authentication, or correctly setup Kerberos, see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server

Comment: That's actually what I assumed, but I thought it was easy enough to add a file to my classpath to try it.  So disregard the second scenario, but I still don't know why the first scenario isn't letting me log in.  The credentials are correct, since I can log in using a GUI.

Comment: `COMP\user` suggests it is a domain account,  which requires integrated security or Kerberos. The username and password authentication in the JDBC driver only works for SQL authentication, not for domain users (IIRC).

Comment: Yeah, it is.  If you look at the first connection string, you'll see `domain=COMP`.  How would I get integrated security working with my current setup? FYI, we are not in charge of the server database, it's managed by a third party company (we're an ecommerce company, and the server is hosted by the company that hosts our website).

Comment: I don't regularly use SQL Server anymore, so I don't know all ins and outs; you might want to retry jTDS or option 1, but then leave out `COMP\\\` from the user name.

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work.  Thanks for your response, though!